# How to create Woocommerce Product Filter Widget

Tags: filters

I want to create Woocommerce Product Filter Widget similar to this :

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-ajax-filters/ 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-ajax-navigation/

I want to create only two features of them "Filter by categories" and "Filter by Price Range", how we can I build such type of Widget.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Krzysiek Dróżdż, I don't want to insult you but, you are not the one who decide how many question I can ask, if you are not able to give answer, please don't put this on hold and give chance to someone else to answer, above question is very clear to specific point, if you are not able to understand it, please don't put it on hold.